# iPhone 13 not using Wi-Fi calling

Tags: iphone, wifi-calling

I have an iPhone 13 set up with Verizon. Calling and data works, but I can't get it to use Wi-Fi calling. My carrier supports it,  its enabled, and I am on Wi-Fi but it does not say VZW Wi-Fi at the top. I have images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpPB2.jpg

Comment: Your phone has wifi turned on, and shows it's connected to the network "x." How do you know wifi calling isn't working?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I know its not working because it says "Verizon" at the top, not "VZW Wi-Fi"

Comment: My iPhone SE (2020), on Verizon via MVNO Ting, doesn't change the top-of-display icons when wifi calling is enabled. What does the display indicate when you manually turn off cellular connectivity? And can you then make a voice call?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Haven't tried doing that yet. I have always had cell service on, but I will try that with airplane mode and being on wifi.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Update: when in airplane mode and on wifi, it works and I can make a voice call and it says VZW WiFi at the top. I still though am confused as to why it seems like the phone prefers using cell service over wifi calling when it can.

Comment: As I said, on my MVNO Verizon cell connection, the iPhone's top-left connectivity icons do not change when cell connectivity is turned on or turned off. Even with cellular turned off, the strength bars of the local cellular signal remain. Why do you think your phone is connecting via cellular?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonics A) I do not use MVNO and B) When I am in airplane mode using WiFi calling, the carrier text does change to "VZW Wi-Fi" and it would not make sense that sometimes the text changes and sometimes it doesnt. I think yours may not change if you are using MVNO.

Comment: That may be so. When was the last time you restarted you phone?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I have done it several times already today, nothing. It still prefers cell data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no other ideas.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Ok, and now that I think about it, I can just turn on airplane mode when I need it, and when there's actually no service, I presume Wi-Fi calling will be preferred.